# Can I define constraints in Pyomo as a list?

Tags: modeling, constraint, convex-optimization, pyomo

I would like to define the following constraint in Pyomo $$W^\top{\bf 1}\le\hat w=\begin{bmatrix}\hat{w}_1&\hat{w}_2&\ldots&\hat{w}_N\end{bmatrix}^\top$$ where $W$ is a $2\times4$ matrix. Can I define the scalar constraints using the entries of $\hat w$ and put these constraints as a list in Pyomo?

```
## First constraint START ##
m.c1 = []
for k in range(N):
    c1_exp = np.matmul((W_var).T,ones_W)[k][0] <= w_hat[k][0]
    m.c1.append(Constraint(expr= c1_exp))
    print(m.c1[k])
## First constraint END ##
```

The output is as follows:

[image: console output]

Does this mean the constraints are created correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the code that you shared shows that simple constraints have been generated, it does not show the constraints. A better way to generate these constraints in Pyomo is to use constraint lists as follow:

```
model.cons1 = ConstraintList()
```

and then in a for loop you will generate the expression for each constraint and add them to the list:

```
model.cons1.add(expr = expression)
```

you can also in each iteration $i$ of for loop observe the generated constraint by:

```
model.cons1[i].pprint()
```

Comment: Thanks @OguzToragay for your reply. I will try this and let you know. :)